# Background div image- repeating issue

Tags: css

I am currently working with a banner i like to place in the background of my header section. The problem I am having is that the image is repeating itself. I have tried using attribute `no-repeat` and in result I do not get anything to show. The image is set as a background for `#header` div. How can i get the image to appear without repeating?

**CSS**

```
<style>
#header {
    height:165px;
    border-top:15px solid #000;
    background-image:  url(http://webprolearner2346.zxq.net/css-test2/images/banner1.png);
}
</stle>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
      <div class="search"><input type="text" class="search-input" name="search" value="Search" onclick="$(this).val('');" /><input type="submit" class="search-submit" /></div>
      <div id="navigation">

       <ul class="button-list">
       <h2>MAIN TITLE PAGE</h2>
        <li><a href="#" class="buttonNav" >Content 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="buttonNav" >Content 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="buttonNav" >Content 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="buttonNav" >Content 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="buttonNav" >Content 5</a></li>   
       </ul> 
      </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Where's the `no-repeat`?

Comment: `background-repeat: no-repeat;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#header {
    height:165px;
    border-top:15px solid #000;
    background-image: url('http://webprolearner2346.zxq.net/css-test2/images/banner1.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

proof: http://awesomescreenshot.com/029cplk1d

but you might as well do it this way:

```
background: url('http://webprolearner2346.zxq.net/css-test2/images/banner1.png') no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

u can get your desired results through this :-

```
#header {
        background-image: url("http://webprolearner2346.zxq.net/css-test2/images/banner1.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        border-top: 15px solid #000000;
        height: 165px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this also;

```
<style>
#header {
    height:165px;
    border-top:15px solid #000;
    background:url(http://webprolearner2346.zxq.net/css-test2/images/banner1.png) no-repeat;
}
</style>
```